# Iterate through nested lists, replacing each instance of a string with a successive letter of the alphabet, beginning again from 'A' for each sublist

Tags: python

I have a list with nested lists:

```
xlist = [[, , , , 'X', , 'X', 'X', , 'X', ,], ['X', , , 'X', , 'X', 'X', 'X',], [, , , 'X', , 'X', ,'X', , , , 'X',]]
```

I want to replace each occurrence of 'X' within a sublist with a letter of the alphabet, in order of occurrence, to end up with this:

```
alist = [[, , , , 'A', , 'B', 'C', , 'D', ,],['A', , , 'B', , 'C', 'D', 'E',], [, , , 'A', , 'B', ,'C', , , , 'D',]]
```

The empty values are important as the list matches another list with the same structure. There is only 1 layer of nested lists and all 'X' values are in sublists.

This has really stumped me so thank you for the help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The empty value here is not a valid list element. Use `''` or `None` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next` for that:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase

xlist = [['', '', '', '', 'X', '', 'X', 'X', '', 'X', '', ''], ['X', '', '', 'X', '', 'X', 'X', 'X', ''], ['', '', '', 'X', '', 'X', '','X', '', '', '', 'X', '']]

def fill_in_x(lst):
    letters = iter(ascii_uppercase)
    return [next(letters) if item == 'X' else item for item in lst]

output = map(fill_in_x, xlist)

for sublst in output:
    print(sublst)

# ['', '', '', '', 'A', '', 'B', 'C', '', 'D', '', '']
# ['A', '', '', 'B', '', 'C', 'D', 'E', '']
# ['', '', '', 'A', '', 'B', '', 'C', '', '', '', 'D', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might do the job:

```py
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZ"

for i, arr in enumerate(xlist):
    char_index = 0

    for j, char in enumerate(arr):
        if char == "X":
            xlist[i][j] = alphabet[char_index]
            char_index += 1
```

Or if you don't want to mutate the first list:

```
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZ"

alist = []

for arr in xlist:
    list_entry = []
    char_index = 0

    for char in arr:
        if char == "X":
            list_entry.append(alphabet[char_index])
            char_index += 1
        else:
            list_entry.append(char)

    alist.append(list_entry)
```

Comment: Use itertools cycle and next() to avoid index error if there are more X values than alphabet letters.

Comment: This worked! I just had to add [0] to line 5 after xlist to iterate through the sublists